# Dois ou mais forms PHP na mesma página

Tags: php, formulário

Eu estou com um pequeno problema, estou a criar uma aplicação e pretendo ter dois *forms* na mesma página.
Acontece que quando executo o primeiro, não tenho problemas, mas quando executo o segundo, o primeiro volta a ser efectuado, e como não tem dados ocorre um erro.
Para tentar contornar este problema eu criei um input hidden:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="opti" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="opti" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="opti" value="3">
```

Sendo que a primeira linha está no primeiro *form* e as outras duas estão no segundo. Pretendia que apesar de estarem na mesma página que não entrassem em conflito e para tal criei um ciclo *if*:

```php
if (isset($_POST['opti']) == '1') 
    {

        // Executa o calculo quando existir


            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST")
            {
                $fabric = $_POST['Fabric'];
                $spare = $_POST['Spare'];
                $xres = $_POST['Xres'];
                $yres = $_POST['Yres'];
                $mspeed = $_POST['Mspeed'];
                $lents = $_POST['Lents'];
                $sensor = 1280;

                Calculos
            }
     }elseif (isset($_POST['opti']) == '2') 
    { tabela}
```

Então quando carrego no primeiro *form*, consigo efectuar todos os cálculos sem problema, mas depois quando quero criar a tabela, com o segundo *form*, volta-me a executar o primeiro e como os campos estão em branco dá erro.

Obrigado.

Código da pagina está aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/akjs061o/

Comment: Posta o resto do seu código aqui, a página completa.

Comment: adicione o código dos `<form>`, somente com os `<input>` é difícil saber o problema

Comment: Para rodar seu código em PHP, você pode publicar nesse site: http://www.viper-7.com/rCOpJR

Comment: Esse  `Calculos` está quebrando seu código.

Comment: Essa palavra Calculos é apenas para indicar que são realizados cálculos nesse espaço, pois é a única coisa que não posso mostrar. Peço que entendam. Obrigado.

Comment: Tem um problema conceitual na pergunta. Não são forms PHP, são forms HTML como quaisquer outros. O PHP só processa o resultado deles (isso ajudaria a entender o problema). Partindo disso, tem outra coisa: o problema pode estar no HTML, que não foi postado na pergunta. Seria legal [edit] a pergunta e colocar toda a parte relevante. É um problema aparentemente simples de se resolver, mas a falta de informação dificulta.

Comment: Olá Bacco, antes de mais obrigado pelo interesse. Todo o meu site está aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/akjs061o/ tal como dito em cima, apenas não está presente os cálculos. Se souber como resolver o problema agradecia uma dica. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE

Eu atualizei o código. Agora os valores são passados para uma página PHP que eu chamei de `calculo.php`. Você só precisa criar essa página e colocar seus cálculos nela, depois, pegue o resultado dessa página e coloque onde desejar na página atual.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pn7x1v40/2/)

Este é só um exemplo!

ORIGINAL

Bem, esse é seu código original editado para o *submit* na mesma página.

Algumas Observações:

1. Não use `isset($_POST)` para verificar se um formulário foi submetido. É melhor usar `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];`
2. Em PHP não é necessário declarar variáveis, pois é uma linguagem do tipo dinâmica (*dynamic type*), isso é um pouco chato, mas assim pode-se desenvolver mais rapidamente, já que PHP foi criado para o RAD (*Rapid Application Development*).
3. A César o que é de César: deixe o JavaScript e o CSS fazerem o lado cliente todo, sem medo. O servidor só deve se preocupar com as requisições que lhe são intrínsecas, como requisições de arquivos e de banco de dados. Enquanto a máquina cliente está fazendo uma requisição no servidor, o seu servidor pode estar recebendo centenas. Isso é Web 2.0!
4. Sempre que possível inclua os códigos JavaScript no fim do arquivo, mas sempre entre as tags `<body></body>`. Assim, será possível que o DOM (*Document Object Model*) seja carregado e aí sim os códigos JavaScript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Calculations</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            table thead tr th, table tbody tr td{
                text-align: center;
            }
            .container{
                width: 75%
            }
        </style>
        <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">

        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="line">
                <header class="header no-print" style="border-bottom: 2px solid gray; margin-bottom: 35px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" name="formulario" method="POST">
                            <div class="container" id="decrease-input">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                        <label for="Fabric">Fabric Wide</label>
                                        <input id="Fabric" name="Fabric" type="text" placeholder="mm" class="form-control input-md">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                        <label for="Spare">Spare width</label>  
                                        <input id="Spare" name="Spare" type="text" placeholder="mm" class="form-control input-md">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                        <label for="Xres">Resolution X</label>  
                                        <input id="Xres" name="Xres" type="text" placeholder="mm/pixel" class="form-control input-md">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                        <label for="Yres">Resolution Y</label>  
                                        <input id="Yres" name="Yres" type="text" placeholder="mm/pixel" class="form-control input-md">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                        <label for="mSpeed">Fabric Max speed</label>  
                                        <input id="mSpeed" name="Mspeed" type="text" placeholder="m/min" class="form-control input-md">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                        <label for="Fabric">Lenses</label>  
                                        <input id="lent" name="Lents" type="text" placeholder="mm" class="form-control input-md">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="reset" id="Bt5" name="Bt5" class="btn btn-inverse">Reset</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="resposta"></div>
                    </div>
                </header >
                <div class="container frame print html2pdf">
                    <header class="header no-print" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                        <img class="right2" src="http://placehold.it/100x65" onclick="javascript:window.print();">
                    </header>
                    <header class="header print">
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Company">Company</label>  
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="Company" name="Company" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md size">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label size" for="Date">Date</label>  
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="Date" name="Date" type="text" placeholder="DD / MM / AAAA" class="form-control input-md size">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <caption> Input </caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Fabric Wide</th>
                                    <th>Spare width</th>
                                    <th>Resolution X</th>
                                    <th>Resolution Y</th>
                                    <th>Max speed</th>
                                    <th>Lenses</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- as celulas abaixo recebem os valores dos formularios acima -->
                                    <td><?php echo $fabric . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $spare . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $xres . "mm/px"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $yres . "mm/px"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $mspeed . "m/min"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $lents . "mm"; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <caption> Calculation </caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Cam number</th>
                                    <th>Space between cam</th>
                                    <th>FOV</th>
                                    <th>Overlap</th>
                                    <th>Height</th>
                                    <th>Pixels</th>
                                    <th>Selected</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $ncam; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $dist . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $fov . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ov . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $alt . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $sensor; ?></td>
                                    <td><input type="radio" name="radio" class="rdo" value="1" id="l1" data-col="1"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $ncam1; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $dist1 . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $fov1 . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ov1 . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $alt1 . "mm"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $sensor; ?></td>
                                    <td><input type="radio" name="radio" class="rdo" value="2" id="l2" ></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- abaixo temos a tabela resultante dos calculos -->
                            <table border="0" class="table table-bordered text-center">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Camera</th>
                                        <th>Left</th>
                                        <th>Right</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="gerar_relatorio" id="gerar_relatorio">Relatorio</button>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Company - Elbit Vision Systems ltd (2015)</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- depois se quiser gerar PDF a partir do canvas, usa isso aqui-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/0.5.0-alpha2/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('form[name="formulario"] input').keydown(function(){
                    //capturando os valores dos formularios
                    var dados_do_formulario = $('form[name="formulario"]').serialize();
                    //enviando os valores por meio do metodo POST para a pagina de calculo[.php]    
                    $.post("calculo.php", {dados: dados_do_formulario}, function(resposta){
                        $(".resposta").html(resposta);
                    });
                });
                
                //gerar PDF
                $('#gerar_relatorio').click(function(){
                    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter'),
                        id_da_parte_html = $('.html2pdf')[0]; //pode ser qualuer seletor na verdade
                    
                    
                    margem = {
                        top: 80,
                        bottom: 60,
                        left: 40,
                        width: 522
                    };
                    pdf.fromHTML(
                    id_da_parte_html,
                    margem.left,
                    margem.top, {
                        'width': margem.width
                    },

                    function (resultado) {
                        pdf.save('teste_html2pdf.pdf');
                    }, margem);

                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Dicas:**

Acesse o [site de boas práticas de código do PHP](https://phpbestpractices.org) ;)

[Veja este exemplo](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest_pt_BR.html) com JavaScript gerando formulários dinâmicos

Comment: Antes de mais obrigado pela resposta. Estive a testar e o resultado infelizmente é o mesmo. A intenção é que onde diz company e date seja so um campo de texto para quando imprimo fique com a referencia. Apenas o a tabela com os input radial é que pertencem ao formulário. Se envio o primeiro tudo é calculado direito, mas quando envo o segundo a pagina é como se efectua-se um reload e fico com os valores a zero quando o que pretendo é continuar os cálculos seleccionando ou uma ou outra opção

Comment: Dentro do loop do{}while() tem um problema. A palavra "Calculos", próxima a while() não foi escapada ou comentada.

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar a melhorar a minha aplicação. Mas continuo com o mesmo problema. quando carrego no submit do segundo form, volto a ficar com os valores todos a zero, não mantendo os dados calculados anteriormente para prosseguir com os cálculos seguintes.

Comment: Eu tô trabalhando nisso. Eu vou aproveitar que você tá usando Bootstrap, isso ajuda muito! A propósito, você pode me dizer se a página systemsibar.php é a mesma que a atual ou se trata de outra página?

Comment: Antes de mais obrigado. Sim é tudo a mesma página, talvez por isso esteja a ter problemas. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu editei seu código. Pode testar funciona, mas os dados do formulários não são salvos, pois são submetidos por meio de POST. Eu recomendo muitíssimo que você use AJAX ou somente JavaScript para gerar os cálculos na View pro usuário, somente quando for necessário o submit é que você deveria usar PHP.

Comment: Antes de mais obrigado, quando diz que editou o código está a referir-se a  http://jsfiddle.net/akjs061o/?

Comment: Eu não editei o JSFiddle, porque eu nunca usei antes e eu não sei se roda o PHP. De qualquer forma, você pode pegar o código no snippet acima e fazer as alterações pra concluir o trabalho.

Comment: Quando respondi ainda não tinha actualizado a pagina e não tinha visto as alterações. Percebo a ideia que me está a tentar passar, criar apenas um form, mas neste caso eu precisava de que não fosse tudo junto, pois uns cálculos são efectuados inicialmente para escolher o numero de câmaras e depois seleccionava a opção pretendida e continuava com os cálculos. Obrigado

Comment: @PedroLima Você pode me explicar o que você está tentando fazer? Você pretende salvar os dados? Quais são as regras para os cálculos dos campos. Mais tarde eu posto um solução com jQuery. É o ideal!!! Bem, agora tenho que ir! Depois eu volto.

Comment: Eu estou a criar uma aplicação com PHPdesktop, para poder utilizar no meu trabalho e depois de testar e ser algo vantajoso partilhar dentro da mesma. Neste momento não pretendo utilizar nenhuma base de dados. A ideia é que com o primeiro form calcule a distancia entre câmaras, a altura ao tecido, a quantidade de pixeis a usar e cria em primeiro uma tabela com o resumo do form e depois outra com os resultados dos cálculos. Nessa segunda tabela pretendia colocar outro form, pois podia escolher 9 ou 10 cam e assim prosseguir e criar uma tabela final. No fim imprimir fisicamente o pdf.

Comment: Por isso é que neste momento a única coisa que pretendia era poder executar o segundo form sem ter de efectuar um reload na pagina toda, permitindo assim conservar todos os cálculos utilizados e não serem alterados para zero. Apenas quando faço o submit do segundo form e que começa os problemas. Sim sei que podia fazer em javascript, mas os meus conhecimentos são muito limitados nessa linguagem dai começar com php e depois quando tivesse algo funcional e por poder aprender, faria o mesmo em Javascript, podendo  até melhorar. Obrigado pela ajuda.